# Find all records (rows) for most recent day of business

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm trying to write a T-SQL script that will be scheduled to run automatically. It should return records relating to the most recent full day of business, i.e. yesterday or, when run on a Monday, last Friday.

I've been asked to provide a report of the number of all open cases at the start of the most recent full day of business (i.e., yesterday or last Friday and the code below is my firs attempt at that, but it doesn't work when run on Monday), as well as all cases opened, all cases closed, and all open cases at the end of the day. This is what I have so far, it provides the opening balance (but it only works when run on Tuesday through Friday... not on Monday):

```
DECLARE @Start DATE = (getdate()-1), @end DATE = getdate()

SELECT
      tc_sk -- the ID
      ,[tc_open_date]
      ,[tc_closed_date]
  FROM tbl_cases
  WHERE tc_open_date<@start
  AND
  tc_closed_date>=@start
  OR
  tc_open_date<@start
  AND
  tc_closed_date is null
```

Again, the problem I'm trying to solve is getting the a list of all the records that were opened during the last day of business. If the script runs on Monday, it should retrieve records entered last Friday. If the script runs Tuesday through Friday, it should retrieve records entered "yesterday".

I'm pretty new at scripting and I'm self taught. Any help you can give me is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a case statement with datepart weekday to check if it's Monday via getdate and if it is Monday then dateadd day -3 else dateadd day -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Declare @Start Date = GetDate() ;

If DateName(DW , @Start) = 'Friday'
    begin
        Set @Start = (getdate()-3);
        SELECT
              tc_sk -- the ID
              ,[tc_open_date]
              ,[tc_closed_date]
        FROM tbl_cases
        WHERE tc_open_date< @start
        AND
        (tc_closed_date>=@start
        OR
        tc_closed_date is null);
    end
        else
            begin
                Set @Start = (getdate()-1);
                SELECT
                     tc_sk -- the ID
                     ,[tc_open_date]
                     ,[tc_closed_date]
                FROM tbl_cases
                WHERE tc_open_date< @start
                AND
                (tc_closed_date>=@start
                OR
                tc_closed_date is null);
            end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Sami,for your quick answer. Does this handle both yesterday (when run Tue through Fri) and last Friday (when run on Mon) ?

Comment: @MelissaPazen Did you try it ? at least try it and can you please show sample data and expected ouputs?

Comment: Sami,I did try it, but it's Friday.  It gives me Thursday and that's great. I guess I have to wait until Monday to see if it will give me Friday's . I just thought you could explain it to me.

Comment: @MelissaPazen So if today is monday it should gives friday?

Comment: @MelissaPazen See the last update , if that what you want please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Flawless!  Thank you, @Sami!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @Start DATE = (getdate()-1), @end DATE = getdate()-1


SELECT
      tc_sk -- the ID
      ,MAX([tc_open_date]) AS tc_open_date
      ,MAX([tc_closed_date]) AS tc_closed_date
  FROM tbl_cases
  WHERE tc_open_date<@start
  AND  (tc_closed_date>=@start  OR  tc_closed_date is null)
  GROUP BY tc_sk
  HAVING MAX([tc_open_date])
```

Comment: Thanks @Tien Nguyen. However I want to retrieve all rows, MAX doesn't help me.